# Ubuntu touch on Nexus 4

Tags: ubuntu-touch

I have finally managed to install the ubuntu touch on my nexus 4. Now the problem is its very Laggy. I have installed the "trusty" latest channel and its quite messy. Change background is not working. Dialer is really slow and everything is messed up. But I have seen many videos of nexus 4 and everything is working smoothly. So do I have to change to or pick any specific channel for installation? Please tell me is their any stable and properly working channel which I should choose for installation or what should I do?

Comment: Try ***14.10 beta*** instead: **`ubuntu-device-flash --channel=ubuntu-touch/utopic --wipe`**

Comment: Ok I'll try that and tell you if it works well

Comment: Channel has a list of number something like 303 etc . i am using Ubuntu Dual boot app in nexus!

Answer (score 1):

Following Ubuntu Dual Boot Install wiki page it is recommended to install "[**utopic**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation#Installing_Ubuntu_from_Android)" channel. It is also possible to switch from a channel installation to another based on the same **[wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/DualBootInstallation#When_installing_Ubuntu.2C_can_I_switch_channels_without_deleting_user_data.3F)**.

Even tough I have installed Ubuntu touch from "trusty" channel on my Nexus 4 (version 303 which is the version I got two days after the final release of trusty 14.04) and it is working good enough (much better than alpha and beta), this should be a stable version.

If you have a lower version than "trusty" 303 you must absolutely update your system. otherwise try the "utopic" channel as suggested by the wiki page.

Comment: I tried the utopic version simply ubunto-touch/utopic but the wifi setting was not working. I have seen everything was working cool in some of the videos on youtube but Y not my nexus !

Comment: I noticed a little wifi glitch with "trusty" v303 during my last ubuntu touch testing. but I am pretty sure it is just a little glitch and it should work fine. I will try to boot ubuntu touch tomorrow morning and let you know if I get any problems with wifi.
Otherwise I am aware that the radio of android 4.3 should be flashed to your phone if you have android 4.4.x because the radio of 4.4.x is not compatible with ubuntu. so you can keep your android 4.4.x as it is but you flash the radio 4.3 on top of it. what I am not sure of is if this affects wifi too or it only affects GSM.

Comment: I am 4.4.x so I think the problem is this only. I just Shifted back to Trusty Latest version and WIFI is working there! I am not sure if everything is working, I'll check it today. BUT there is NO SCREEN ROTATION and some other important settings are missing!